# Como enviar varios correos electronicos en segundo plano?

Tags: c#, email, backgroundworker

Tengo una lista de correos que lo obtengo desde mi base de datos y utilizo la funcion de enviar email dentro de un for, pero eso deja en espera a la pagina aspx. Com enviar correo en segundo plano para todos los correos de la lista.
Algun ejemplo.

Comment: Estas personalizando el body del mail para cada destinatario? por segundo plano te refieres a usar un thread (un hilo separado) ?

Comment: Recuerda Ricardo que las publicaciones en el sitio deben ser realizadas en base a [ask]. No has realizado el [tour] del sitio, es importante para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no estoy personalizando para cada uno de los mail. envio un mail general para todas las cuentas de correo. A segundo plano si la solucion en un hilo seria genial.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas un `foreach` o un `thread`, puede tener la lista y ponerla toda junta en el `blind carbon copy (BCC)` si es que no quieres que el resto se entere a quien le llega los mails

[MailMessage.Bcc Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=netframework-4.5)

entonces solo harias

```
//resto codigo

foreach(var row in dt.Rows){
  MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress(row["email"].ToString());
  mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bcc);
}

smtp.Send();
```

con solo eso al realizar el `send` le llegara a todos los destinos que definas

Comment: Esta respuesta es buena pero hay que tener en cuenta el límite de envío de cada proveedor. Es decir, por ejemplo Gmail tiene límites de 100-150 si no los envías vía su portal web.

Comment: en la pregunta no se especifica la cantidad de destinatarios, pero en caso de haber un limite por mail conociento la cantidad se podria agrupar en bloques que no supere el limite, siempre van a ser mas rapido que enviar cada mail de forma individual

Comment: Si, lo indicaba para que OP lo tuviera en cuenta. Muchas gracias @Leandro

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra utilizo office365 y en  mi aplicación los correos maximos a enviar seran unos 30 ¡, no más.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
List<String> correos = /* Lista de correos que obtengo desde base de datos */

Parallel.ForEach(correos, correo =>
{
    var mail = new MailMessage("yo@yo.com", correo);
    var client = new SmtpClient("proveedor.mail.com", 25);

    mail.Subject = "Asunto";
    mail.Body = "Cuerpo";
    client.Send(mail);
});
```

El propio runtime se encargará de hacer una tarea por cada correo a enviar. La operación en global será síncrona (no se acabará la llamada a `Parallel.ForEach` hasta que hayan acabado todos los elementos) pero cada elemento puede llamarse asíncronamente.